# Adding application home button long press

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

How to add own application when home button long press with a standard launcher and ROM?

Comment: The home button long press behvaiour varies a lot depending on device, OEM, ROM and Android version. Which behaviour are you talking about?

Comment: when i long press home button, appears the msgbox that lists the applications (Google Search, KLets (that is another application like google search). I want add my application...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Home Button Launcher App:

[Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamicg.homebuttonlauncher)